# Inserting html div value in js var

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, send

I have the following code at bottom of page to update amount (p_amount) and package id (pack_id) (all codes are in same page)

```
       jQuery.ajax({                    
        url : ajaxurl,                   
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        data : search_params,
        success : function(response){
            if(response.code=='success'){                           
                jQuery('#coupon-result').html('<img src="<?php echo WP_iv_membership_URLPATH; ?>admin/files/images/right_icon.png">');
            }else{
                    jQuery('#coupon-result').html('<img src="<?php echo   WP_iv_membership_URLPATH; ?>admin/files/images/wrong_16x16.png">');
            }
            jQuery('#p_amount').html(response.p_amount);

                }
```

after this, It updates the value here

```
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 " id="p_amount">
```

and here in the middle of page i am using js to send values over my payment gateway provider, I want to insert the updated value of amount(p_amount) inside 
(var amount), but it never updates

```
 <div class="checkout">    
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var amount       = 'p_amount';
    var currency     = 'USD';
```

Comment: Use a global variable and update the values.

Comment: If I use window.location.href and send value in url, i can store it in php and print it, but the problem is I don't want the page to get refresh. So using this way then

Answer (score -1):

Update js varible in response function.

```
jQuery.ajax({                    
        url : ajaxurl,                   
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        data : search_params,
        success : function(response){
            if(response.code=='success'){                           
                jQuery('#coupon-result').html('<img src="<?php echo WP_iv_membership_URLPATH; ?>admin/files/images/right_icon.png">');
                amount = response.p_amount;
            }else{
                    jQuery('#coupon-result').html('<img src="<?php echo   WP_iv_membership_URLPATH; ?>admin/files/images/wrong_16x16.png">');
            }
            jQuery('#p_amount').html(response.p_amount);

                }
```

Comment: Iam sorry, I didn't get you all of them are updated and correct

Comment: The output is still like this ->

var amount       = 'package_amount';

where as It should get updated with some numbers

Comment: sorry this-> var amount       = 'p_amount';

Comment: Oh I got you need remove that variable from the middle of page `amount` and `currency` and initialize in the response function of Ajax.
Like above answer.

Comment: this code,
jQuery('#p_amount').html(response.p_amount);

updates the div containing id=p_amount

but when I use this here,
var amount       = 'p_amount';

this var amount gets nothing.

Comment: Look I need to send value to payment service provide in the form of this variable.

var amount = '1234'

All I need to do is insert valid value in this field, where as I have div containg id 'p_amount' and this id has that value.

and below code is used to update this id,
 jQuery('#p_amount').html(response.p_amount);


hope it make more sense now

Comment: When you place var before the variable it is limited to function. but you are using this variable in whole page then remove the var and make it global.

Comment: but I do not have any variable like p_amount, all I have is this -> jQuery('#p_amount').html(response.p_amount); and this updates the id'p_amount' I want result of this id  in my var amount

Comment: What I am saying is when your Ajax is done store the value in global variable like `amount = response.p_amount;`
Then assign the value to your script like 
`var amount = amount;`
removing `var` from js variable makes it global and you can use it anywhere in the script.

Comment: I got it bro I did it, but nothing changed

Comment: I am using this as global variable aamount = response.p_amount; and then calling it this way ->  var amount       = 'aamount';

nothing got changed. :(

Comment: Then your script is being called before the ajax response. for this what you can do place the whole script which is in middle in the response function.

Comment: I pasted the calling js under the response function

Comment: can make fiddle of your code ? just to see the code it's ok if ajax doesn't work.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/4m6p9euh/ just keep the css and checkout div. and remove script tag as i've placed into the response function.

Comment: BTW you don't need to include jQuery again once you have jQuery in your project so skip that append code. But I don't understand where these variable are being used to render button ?

Comment: Bro, I cannot merge them as I have to submit that checkout div as it is, its fixed api, I can only insert value in it

Comment: see you need to understand the flow of checkout div code. It is designed to load on page load and you are moving it to js callback function. so better way keep this on another page. and redirect using js with query string. but this is not safe anyone can change the query string and alter the information.

Comment: Now I am sorry :P i can only help you further if you let us know what is the trouble to load checkout button on js callback.

Comment: I check out the paytabs you can do this just insert this js after the div in callback function like `jQuery('.checkout').after('<script src="https://www.paytabs.com/js/express_checkout.js"><\/script>');` and keep all variable in callback function as it is. It will work.

Comment: try to read it again, here
http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_malik/4m6p9euh/1/ 

Im sure m doing a litle silly mistake